# Instrument Activity that runs on foreign process

Tags: android

I have two applications X and Y. Application X has one activity "A" that needs to run on the application Y`s process. I am trying to create an instrumentation test like bellow:

public class ATest extends SingleLaunchActivityTestCase {...}

The issue is that when I point the AndroidManifest.xml of my test application to instrument process X I get the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Intent in process test.application.a resolved to different process test.application.b

I expected that since if activity A runs on process Y the instrumentation framework must run on the same target process Y.

But if I change to instrument process Y then the following error occurs:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
    at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:239)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test.application.a.A

I guess that happens since on application Y there is no class test.application.a.A!

Is this a limitation from the instrumentation framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent resolved to different process when running Unit Test in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445247/intent-resolved-to-different-process-when-running-unit-test-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

As I know it seems that the Instrumentation tests run on the same process of the tested application. Take a glance here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html#Overview .

Can't you somehow create a mock "Y" application?

Best regards.