# Intent in process resolved to different process

Tags: android, unit-testing, process

There are two activities in my app A and B, Activity A is the mainactivity.
In `androidmanifest.xml` file, activity B describes with android:process property, like `android:process=":C"`.

In my unit testing project, I want to test activity B, I use startActivitySync method to start  activity B, but i got a `java.lang.runtimexception:Intent in process A resolved to different process A:C.`

I do not know how to solve it, somebody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent resolved to different process when running Unit Test in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445247/intent-resolved-to-different-process-when-running-unit-test-in-android)